# Volkswagen Jetta Oil Pan Change

Tags: vw, oil-leak

So recently I hit a speed bump and cracked a small section on the oil pan. I ordered one and received it. The problem is getting off the oil pan. On opposite sides there are about 6-7 screws which my friend and I have taken off. But the difficulty comes while trying to access two specific screws which are at an impossible angle. The thing is that the screws are not completely in line, which makes it very hard to screw them out from a 90 degree angle. How can I get these screws out? Will I have to use a specific battery operated tool or normal husky work tools? It's  a 2001 Jetta with a 2.0 4 cylinder engine.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to post pictures in your post. If you will comment on this post with links to the pictures I will attach them to your post

Comment: Also you will want to edit your post to include model year and engine size, as well as transmission type

Answer (score 2):

Swivels, extensions, shallow sockets, and a ratchet.

Depending on what is blocking access you may have to remove/unbolt something else or lift the engine slightly to gain access.

In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q51ws737EEQ) video he had to remove the belt from his AC compressor and move it slightly. Not sure what year of Jetta in the video though.

Comment: Thanks man luckily my friend and I didn't have to do that much. We finally got access to the screws by using a wobble head. It was a bit tedious, but it was a job well done.

Comment: The video states in the beginning it is 2000 (first year of that Mk. IV generation, same as OP), just different engine (TDI).

Comment: @theUg ah I checked it at work, I had the volume off.